# find the derivative of a function that involves complex-valued matrices

Tags: matrix-calculus

Consider the following function $f(\bf x)$:
$f(\bf x) = \left\|(\bf A \bf x) \circ {(\bf A \bf x)}^* - \bf c\right\|_2^2$,
where

- $\bf A \in {\mathbb C}^{N\times M}$ (complex-valued matrix)
- $\bf x \in {\mathbb C}^{M \times1}$ (complex-valued vector)
- $\bf c \in {\mathbb R}^{N \times1}$ (real-valued vector)
- $\left\| \right\|_2$ denotes the $l_2$ norm
- $\circ$ denotes the Hadamard product
- $^*$ denotes the conjugate operation.

The aim is to compute the derivative of $f(\bf x)$ with respect to $\bf x$.

This might involve some notion and techniques of complex-valued matrix differentiation, which I am not familiar. Can anyone point out some references on solving this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend the book "Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives" by Are Hjorungnes. He's also published some PDF articles with roughly the same title, which you can Google.

Comment: Thanks. I will read the material you pointed out.

Comment: $(Ax)\circ (Ax)^*$ is not defined except if $*$ is the conjugate operation; in this case it's a bad notation.

Comment: On the other hand, if $x$ varies in $\mathbb{C}$, then the function $x\rightarrow |x|^2$ has no derivative wrt. $x$.

Comment: In terms of Wirtinger derivatives, you can write 
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2A^T(b^*\circ b\circ b^*-b^*\circ c) \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^*} &= 2A^H(b\circ b^*\circ b-b\circ c) \cr
}$$ where $\,b=Ax$